# bash: bower: command not found with NVM

Tags: bower, nvm

I use `nvm` and I have McAfee with Windows 10 (so my `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules` is empty at the beginning, so I copy/paste manualy all `node_modules` (with `bower` and `bower-config`) inside.

I use this:

```
npm install bower -g
```

And

```
npm bower --version
```

> 5.5.1

but

```
bower --version
```

> bash: bower: command not found

**EDIT:**

`npm bower --version` `5.5.1` is not `bower` verion but `npm` version!!

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10 + `NVM`

```
npm config set prefix /c/Users/xxxxxxx/AppData/Roaming/nvm/v8.9.2
npm install -g bower
bower --version
```

> 1.8.8